# xslt1.0/xml - why will xsl file stop rendering xml when namespace information is added

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got an xsl file that has been working fine. The templates are all in place and everything shows on the page when the root node is the following:

```
<Document>
  <...>
</Document>
```

However, if namespace information is added to the xml document like so:

```
<Document  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi_schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA_SDTC.xsd" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">
  <...>
</Document>
```

My stylesheet hasn't changed and it was working for the first example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:template match="/">
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There's nothing being read from the xml document at all on the web output. What would be the cause for that?

I made the following change to the XSLT file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA_SDTC.xsd" 
xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" 
xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3" 
xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc"
>
```

but that throws an error on the xsi:schemaLocation because of the space between v3 and CDA. If I take out that one line like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" 
xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3" 
xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc"
>
```

Then I still get nothing rendered out of the xml document onto the page. I know I'm missing something but I'm not familiar enough with xsl to know what it is.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems now, your root element 'Document' belongs to namespace xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" and you must include it in your XSLT

Comment: Does that mean just adding to the xmlns list at the top of the xslt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 1.0 expressions, unprefixed names *always* refer to nodes that are not in a namespace.  If you want to refer to nodes that are in a namespace then you need to bind the relevant namespace URI to a prefix in the stylesheet and use that prefix in your XPaths.

In your example the document

```
<Document>
  <!--...-->
</Document>
```

has a root element with the local name `Document` and no namespace, so it can be matched by an XPath expression of `/Document`.  But the document

```
<Document  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi_schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA_SDTC.xsd" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">
  <!--...-->
</Document>
```

has a root element with local name `Document` in the `urn:hl7-org:v3` namespace, which is *not* matched by the path `/Document`.  In order to match that you would need to add

```
xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3"
```

to the `<xsl:stylesheet>` tag, and then use XPath expressions like `/hl7:Document`.  Since the default namespace `xmlns="..."` applies to descendant elements as well, you'll probably find that you have to add this prefix in many places, e.g. `/Document/a/b` would probably need to change to `/hl7:Document/hl7:a/hl7:b`.  In XSLT 2.0 you can use [`xpath-default-namespace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unprefixed-qnames) but this option is not available in 1.0.

The fact that the element name doesn't have a prefix in the original XML is irrelevant - what matters to XPath is the local name and the namespace URI.

Comment: I currently have xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" in the stylesheet. It's throwing an error if i put another in. How do I reconcile that and if I replace the xmlns with what's in the xml document, do I still need to prefix the xpath expressions?

Comment: @jjasper0729 you don't need to add the `xmlns=...` to the stylesheet, only the prefix mapping `xmlns:hl7=...` and the `hl7:` prefixes in the expressions.  The prefixes you use in the stylesheet don't have to match those in the document, the important thing is the URIs the prefixes are mapped to.

Comment: That is working now with the hl7: prefix added to everything. Is there a way with xslt1.0 to make that the default so I don't have to put that into everything? It's a big file with a lot of nodes that would need that.

Comment: @jjasper0729 No.  As I say in the answer, XSLT 2.0 has `xpath-default-namespace` but in XSLT 1.0 no prefix always means no namespace.

Comment: So I'll just need to drop the hl7: in for all nodes and everything.. this I can do. Was just hoping I wouldn't have to. Thanks for the information on it.

Comment: @jjasper0729 all _element_ nodes, remember that an `xmlns="..."` doesn't apply to attributes so `/foo/bar/@baz` would need to become `/hl7:foo/hl7:bar/@baz`.

Comment: Right. That's how I'm doing it and getting my values back. Just having to go through all of them. Thanks for the help

Comment: One more quick question though. I have the prefix working in the xslt file, but I also have a .net vb file that I have to open the xml document and find a particular node and read it and then rewrite the xml document with the contents of that node (it's convoluted I know, but this particular value has to be done this way). It's not quite working. How would I open up this node with the new namespace in the .net file?

Comment: @jjasper0729 I've no idea, I don't know .net.  Your best bet would be to ask that as a separate SO question with the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your input XML no contains a default namespace `xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"`. This means your XSLT also needs to know this namespace.

The XSLT processor matches on the namespace URI. So in your XSLT you can use a different prefix, for example putting `xmlns:pref="urn:hl7-org:v3"` in your XSLT.

You could than select elements in your XSLT with use of that prefix: `<xsl:value-of select="/pref:rootElement/pref:childElement" />`

Comment: I put in some edits to show different tests I have done changing the xmlns values but to no avail.